# Addition of a new value to API response

Tags: php, laravel, api

Currently learning Laravel and any help is much appreciated!
My API controller has the following `index` function

```
public function index()
{
    abort_if(Gate::denies('course_access'), Response::HTTP_FORBIDDEN, '403 Forbidden');

    $response=Course::all()->toArray();
    
    $allData = [];
    foreach (Course::all() as $ids=>$CMF) {
        
        UNSET($response[$ids]['media']);

        $data_sequence = DB::table('media_sequence')->where('data_id', $CMF["id"])->where('type','CMF')->first();

        $data_id=$data_sequence->id;
        $data_sequence = json_decode($data_sequence->data_sequence);
        $data = [];
        $data["id"] = $CMF["id"];
        $data["title"] = $CMF["title"];
            
        foreach ($data_sequence as $id => $dataSeq) {
            if ($dataSeq->type == "Text") {
                $response[$ids]['media'][]=["id"=>$data_id,"text"=> $dataSeq->name,"mime_type"=>"text"];
            } elseif ($dataSeq->type == "file") {
                foreach ($CMF["media"] as $file) {
                    if (str::slug($dataSeq->name) == str::slug($file["file_name"])) {
                        $file["thumb"] = $file->getUrl('video_thumb');
                        $response[$ids]['media'][]=$file;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $allData[] = $data;
    }
    return new CourseResource($response);

    //Commented: return new CourseResource(Course::with(['category', 'assigned_teams', 'team'])->get());
}
```

Getting no result when trying to return `'assigned_teams'` with `$response`
The API response still doesn't include `'assigned_teams'`

I tried: `return new CourseResource($response, 'assigned_teams');`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question here, but I would like to point out that this code looks a bit messy. (a) You are doing `Course::all()` twice which will hit the database twice to get the exact same data (b) you have the N+1 problem in that you are doing a database query for each model retrieved. You might want to take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships for how you can define a relationship on Courses and eager load all related models you need at once. Also take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources on mapping responses to a specific form

Comment: Also you can use an [array cast](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting) to cast `data_sequence` to an array without needing to do it manually but that will require you to create an Eloquent model for rows of `media_sequence`

Comment: media_sequence is returning data fine, I just need to also return 'assigned_teams' with $response. I think its one line modification only where 
return new CourseResource($response);

Comment: Try using `Course::with('assigned_teams')->all()` instead of `Course::all()` (in both places...)

Comment: From you code, I assume `assigned_teams` is a relationship. Since the line is commented, it is not being included in the response array.

Comment: Please provide code for your `CourseResource`

Answer (score 0):

It is not returning the `assigned_items` since it is not included in the `$response` array.

Change

```
$response=Course::all()->toArray();
```

To

```
$response=Course::with(['category', 'assigned_teams', 'team'])->get();
```

Read more: [eager-loading-multiple-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading-multiple-relationships)
Btw, as @apokryfos mentioned, you should refactor your code using `Eloquent Relationships` and `Eager Loading`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the assigned_teams are not handled in your `CourseResource`.
You need to extend your resource to respect this additional relation.

```php
class CourseResource extends JsonResource
{

    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,

            // return teams if they have been loaded
            'teams' => TeamsResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('assigned_teams')),
        ];
    }
}
```

This is just exemplary, since you did not provided your code for `CourceResource` yet, you need to update it according to your needs.

Here is the link to the appropriate laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#conditional-relationships